# Button doesn't work inside vaadin-grid (javascript)

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-grid, lit

I have a button in a vaadin grid that I want to open a link in a new tab, but it doesn't work inside the grid. I tested the code outside the grid, and it worked there. Everything is done using Lit.

Here's part of the code:

```
<vaadin-grid-column resizable="" path="action" header="Action">
  <template>
    <button @click="${this._openTab()}"Test</button>
  </template>
</vaadin-grid-column>
```

The _openTab function:

```
_openTab(e){
  window.open("https://google.com", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: The link in _openTab() will be replaced with a variable.

Comment: I also tried using location.href, but this also didn't work in the vaadin-grid.

Comment: Unsure without a reproducible example, but there are some bugs in the code sample. For example you've not closed the `button` opening tag. And you're also calling the `_openTab` method and binding its return value (undefined) instead of binding the method itself. Fix: `<button @click="${this._openTab}">Test`. I removed the `()` and added `>`.